# QueryDSL/HQL using ordinal instead of desired String value in the on-part of a leftJoin

Tags: hql, querydsl

I get the following error when running my query

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FEHLER: Operator existiert nicht: bigint = character varying
```

The important part of the query:

```
[...]
    query.leftJoin(qSomeObj.obj2, qObj2).on(qObj2.col1.eq(enumValue);
    query.where(qSomeObj.obj2.isNull());
[...]
```

The field in my value object is annotated as below:

```
[...]
@Column(name = "col1", nullable = false)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private MyEnum col1;
[...]
```

It seems like the final SQL Query contains the ordinal of the enumValue instead of the desired *String*. If I put the same Predicate into a where clause there is no such error, hence it seems like it is reacting on the annotation in the value object and using the *String*.

Is this some kind of bug in either QueryDSL or Hibernate? Or maybe I am doing something wrong. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

EDIT:

I think I got it wrong the first time. It's not the enum ordinal which is messing with my query. In fact, the enum is treated as a *String*, hence "the charactery varying" in the error message. 
But the parameter order is messed up. Additionaly to the parts I already posted, I have a customer filter on each relation. This is a bigint, so my queries first parameter should be the customerId but is the name of the enum value.

Comment: That should be supported. What are your Hibernate and Querydsl versions?

Comment: Hibernate 4.2.1.FINAL and QueryDSL 3.2.2

Comment: Looks now more like a Hibernate bug.